# How to handle App Settings JSON file in App Service Deployment Slots

Tags: azure-appservice, .net-4.8

I have to deploy Dotnet application (Target Framework is 4.7) in Azure App Service using Azure DevOps Pipeline and manually. And it has three deployment slots like Dev, QA and Staging. Is there any way to handle appsetting.json for deployment slots? (I mean if I have appsettings.development.json, appsetting.QA.json...)

Comment: Please refer [Handle Application Configuration](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/handling-application-configuration/)

Comment: Could you please share your folder structure. Do you have ```web.config``` or ```appsettings.json```,because appsettings.json is used for ```.Net CORE``` applications.Please confirm.